# Where does the energy come from when Vacuum fluctuations move an object?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, energy-conservation, vacuum, ligo

[A couple of years ago an experiment](https://www.ligo.caltech.edu/news/ligo20200701) in Ligo showed that vacuum fluctuations can exert a force on macroscopic objects (although this is extremely small). Nevertheless this opens up the question, where the energy for the displacement comes from? If the fluctuations really do work on the mirror then doesn't that mean that the energy of the vacuum fluctuations have to be lowered? But the vacuum state is the lowest possible energy state, so how can that be lowered even further?

Comment: The answer is that there are no vacuum fluctuations. Every scenario in which we pick up "quantum noise", if you will, requires an excited quantum field state. If the article does not explain what that state is, then it's not written well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article that is linked to basically refers to "quantum fluctuations" and not "vacuum fluctuations" (except in one quote, which I suspect is misplaced). What these quantum fluctuations refer to are the fluctuations that one sees in the number of photons that are detected within a certain period due to the Poisson statistics of the laser in the LIGO interferometer (often called "shot noise"). They also explain there that they can reduce the noise with the aid of a "squeezer". It is known that squeezed states can reduce the amount of shot noise below the so-called standard quantum limit, which means what is possible for classical states (like laser light).

The idea that one can extract energy from the vacuum is in contradiction with the conservation laws of physics. Energy is a conserved quantity, which via Noether's theorem, relates to the fact that the laws of nature are invariant to a shift in time. If we can extract energy from the vacuum, then it is not conserved. That can only happen if the laws of nature are not invariant to time translations.

Answer (score 1):

You could similarly ask this question: where does the energy come from when you burn coal? The answer there is that the energy was stored in the electromagnetic fields around and between the carbon atoms in the coal and the oxygen atoms in the oxygen molecules. In this case, when the objects move the vacuum changes. The vacuum is not something invariant in which these objects sit. The whole reason forces pop up is because the objects suppress the vacuum fluctuations inside of themselves. This affects the way the vacuum near the objects can fluctuate in ways that make it so that energy is released when they move closer to each-other.

Thus, the short answer, is that the energy is stored in the vacuum fields around the objects, and that energy gets released as the objects get closer to each-other.

Comment: I don't understand. I know that the vacuum has an energy level. But if the mirror is moved by a vacuum fluctuation, then work is done. This work has to come from somewhere, in other words the energy of the system doing the work has to be lowered. The only possibility I can think of is the vacuum. But the vacuum is the lowest energy level and cannot be lowered. I think what you are referring to is the Casimir effect, but I am not sure if in the publication this is what is talked about.

Comment: @eeqesri I am, indeed, describing the Casimir effect. It's the only force that originates from the vacuum that I know of. What they're talking about [in the original paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-020-2420-8) is indeed not that. It's about quantum fluctuations arising from the mirror and laser beam becoming entangled/correlated.

Comment: @eeqesri "But the vacuum is the lowest energy level and cannot be lowered." Keep in mind that the vacuum you're thinking of is not the vacuum of the casimir force. The true vacuum is the lowest energy level, but the vacuum observed from the Casimir effect is the effective vacuum after introducing macroscopic objects (specifically conductors, iirc) that change the electromagnetic vacuum.

Comment: Of course, the vacuum when there are mirrors is different in-between than outside. I must admit that I have to read the paper completely. Right now I don't have access. So this will take some time.

Comment: @eeqesri I haven't read the paper, either, but based on the abstract I can conclude that they're talking about quantum fluctuations, which are not the same thing as vacuum fluctuations (the latter are a subset of the former).

Comment: Ok I get it. I thought quantum fluctuations and vacuum fluctuations are synonymous, but now I understand they are not. Even in a state which is not the vacuum there can be fluctuations. Is it basically the variance of an observable?

Comment: @eeqesri Not quite. There are other sources of variance, like outside noise and thermal fluctuations. So it's the contribution of quantum uncertainty to the total variance.

Comment: Ok. thanks for clarifying my doubt.